# Execute actions after specific commands in Apache Guacamole SSH

Tags: ssh, security, shell

I setup `Apache Guacamole 0.9.14` on my `CentOS 7` with `nginx` as reverse proxy to it.

I want to give limited access to some of my employees for some of my servers via `ssh`.

Some of them are `SFTP` enabled and to prevent sabotage on purpose or not I edit guacamole upload function to upload a copy of file uploaded on guacamole server itself alongside destination server.

I was wondering if I could create a copy of files getting on destination servers via `wget`, `curl`, etc.

If I can control specific commands on destination servers and do some actions before executing them, (For example backing files on guacamole server before executing any `rm -rf` command or creating a copy of file `'wget'`ed on guacamole server), that would be great.

There are more than a thousand servers with different Linux OSs on them, so editing any server except guacamole server itself is impossible to do.

Any idea on how to control commands before executing on guacamole server specially on `ssh`?

---

I answered my own question, but as you read my answer you can know I didn't actually answer my question, so I'm not accepting mine and any better ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any way to achieve my goal, but I did find a little tricky way to do that in my servers.

I changed some of my commands like `wget` to `wget2` and wrote my own `wget` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget2 $1 -P /tmp > /dev/null 2>&1 & wget2 $1
```

A little more explanation:

I moved `/usr/bin/wget` to `/usr/bin/wget2` therefore I have the original `wget` and then I wrote my own `wget` which while it downloads link to this directory, also downloads a copy into `/tmp` folder which doesn't show any output to command line.

I know that user can realize `wget2` is running when he/she executes `ps` (lists process), but I don't care about that because he knows I'm supervising:)

It's just the case of audit.